# Tracking multiple Conversions in one session - Implementation problems

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, conversion-tracking

I need to track multiple conversions of the same conversion event in the same session.

Due to the reason that Analytics can only fire one Conversions per Conversion Goal in one Session, I'm going to use the Transaction Handler.

Everytime the page "/sucess/" is called I want to submit a transaction to Analytics.

I used the Tag Manager to do so, but somehow the Transactions are not transferred at all to Analytics.

1. I activated Enhanced E-Commerce tracking in Analyitcs
2. I Implemented the following code on the /sucess/ page

[image]

COMMENT: I REALLY TRIED; BUT I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO EDIT CODE ON THIS WEBPÜAGE PROPERLY

3. Aditionally I am firing a Tag with Tag Type: Google Analytics, Tracking Type: Transaction on the "/sucess/" page.

No Transactions appearing in Analytics. Any Ideas?
As far as I understood all mandatory fields are beeing used in my Script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how to get it to show up in the transaction area, but you could create them as an event in analytics. They will show up under behaviour and events. Then just name the category and label as transaction and it will store all the data. You just need to set up a new tag in TM and use track type "Event" and your trigger should work fine for it. Are you just trying to find out how many people are getting to the page or do you want the data to show how much they have spent? Hope this helps you out

Comment: Thank for your Help! But unfortunately I need the Transaction Data in order to connect it from there to Google Ads other services. If I only use Events and declare them as Conversions I will always only see one conversions per session, eventhough some keywords/users/... may have triggered more than one conversion.